# False hyperref when using Listoffigures in amsbook

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, amsbook

it's me again. I'm working with `amsbook`at the moment and I want to include listoffigures and listoftables into my document. Since this document is supposed to be useable online, I included the `hyperref`-package. But if I click on the listoffigures in my TOC, I am jumping to the preface and not to the LOF. The same happens with the listoftables. Does anybody know why?

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsbook}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\chapter*{Preface}
Hello to everybody!

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\mainmatter

\end{document}
```

Comment: well amsbook quite thoroughly disables the hyperref support. You can try `\cleardoublepage\phantomsection\listoftables` to add an anchor.

Comment: It works fine, thank you